# Is there a way to force Landscape mode in SwiftUI for only certain views?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, landscape

SwiftUI is still fairly new and it has abstracted much of the functionality of code away. So I'm uncertain of the appropriate way of forcing landscape mode on only particular views, not every view.

Does anyone know a clean and consistent way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
                Text("landscape")
            } else {
                Text("Potrait")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can get some idea about size class here https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/

Comment: this may helpful too .. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126878

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I needed, but it did find it helpful. It definitely offers a new set of possibilities. Thanks!

Comment: mm seems like overriding environment  variable also does not work !,